# I have replaced the information in my database by another by accident and I want to recover it, but I don't have a backup

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I was doing tests and by accident I wrote the information on a label that contained a lot of valuable information, the problem is that I don't have a backup and I couldn't export before, I need help, I really need the information that I deleted by accident, I saw in google cloud the log of when the request was made. But it does not show me the data that was deleted, it only shows me permission data, times, and more. I want to know if this information is recoverable or not. The database that I use and where all this happens is Real DataBase. Thanks in advance.

I reviewed in google cloud and I expected to see my data along with the records that I did see, but the data from my database did not :c

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if this information is recoverable or not.

Unfortunately, it is not, unless you have a previous backup that contains that data. To avoid this kind of situation, do not perform update operations on the real database but create another database for tests. When you're absolutely sure, perform the operations on the real database. Besides that, you can also take into consideration versioning your data. This means that when you want to update some data, add it instead of updating it. In this way, you'll have the old version of the data along with the new version. If you're 100% sure that it's what you need, you can go ahead and delete the previous one if you want.

Comment: Hey Jose. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?